# Oracle: How to call an overloaded procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, encryption, plsql, ora-06553

How to properly call `DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.DESEncrypt`? (without using PL/SQL if possible)

```
select DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.DESEncrypt('x','y') from dual;
```

doesn't work because DESEncrypt is overloaded:

```
ORA-06553: PLS-307: Too many declarations of "DESENCRYPT" match this call
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Is there a way to choose one implementation of DESENCRYPT (possibly the VARCHAR2 variant) to avoid this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here you go, just let it know which overload to use by supplying the param names!

```
select DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.DesEncrypt(INPUT_STRING=>'11112abc',KEY_STRING=>'4578ccde') 
from dual ;
```

returns

> M5��w5Z

note, your key needs to be at least 8 bytes:

> ORA-28234: key length too short
>   ORA-06512: at
>   "SYS.DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT_FFI",
>   line 21 ORA-06512: at
>   "SYS.DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT", line
>   126
>   28234. 00000 -  "key length too short"
>   *Cause:    The key specified is too short for the algorithm. DES
>              requires a key of at least 8 bytes. Triple DES requires a
>              key of least 16 bytes in two-key mode and 24 bytes in three-key
>              mode.
>   *Action:   Specify a longer key.

---

You may always try it with a wrapper function (as tony suggested)

```
create or replace
function DesEncrypt(pinputString IN VARCHAR2 , pKeyString in VARCHAR2) RETURN varchar2
IS
BEGIN
return DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.DesEncrypt(INPUT_STRING=>INPUTSTRING,KEY_STRING=>KEYSTRING);
END DesEncrypt;
/
select DesEncrypt('11112abc' , '4578ccde') from dual ;
```

---

Since you are on 10g, you may want to use the DBMS_CRYPTO package
http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/network.101/b10773/apdvncrp.htm

Comment: I'm getting 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: I think the formatter ate the "from dual"  - see below the code sample.

Comment: unfortunately not, i already added the "from dual". (I am using Oracle 10g)

Comment: @MRalwasser, fixed the dual bit.  I am using 11gR2 so that may make the difference, try the wrapper function but also look into Crypto.

Answer (score 9):

In Oracle 11G you can use named notation like this:

```
select DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.DESEncrypt(input_string=>'x',key_string=>'y')
from dual;
```

I don't think it is possible to call these functions unambiguously in earlier versions of Oracle, except by creating a wrapper function and calling that instead.

Comment: I'm getting an ORA-00907: "missing right parenthesis" error (I'm using Oracle 10g)

Comment: Indeed you will.  As I said, you can only use named notation in SQL from Oracle 11G onwards.

Answer (score 2):

here's a crypt/decrypt using the older dbms_obfuscation_toolkit:

```
create or replace function crypt(p_str in varchar2, p_key in varchar2) return varchar2
as
  l_data varchar2(255);
begin
  l_data := rpad(p_str, (trunc(length(p_str)/8)+1)*8,chr(0));
  dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESEncrypt
  (input_string=>l_data,
  key_string=>p_key,
  encrypted_string=>l_data);

  return l_data;
end;
```

And for decrypt:

```
create or replace function decrypt(p_str in varchar2, p_key in varchar2) return varchar2
as
  l_data varchar2(255);
begin
  dbms_obfuscation_tookit.DESDecrypt
  (input_string=>p_str,
  key_string=>p_key,
  decrypted_string=>l_data);

  return rtrim(l_data,chr(0));
end;
```

And usage:

```
declare

  l_data varchar2(100);
  l_key varchar2(100);
  l_encrypted varchar2(100);
  l_decrypted varchar2(100);

begin
  l_data := 'This is secret!!!';
  l_key := 'My secret key';
  dbms_output.put_line(l_data);

  l_encrypted := crypt(l_data, l_key);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_encrypted);

  l_decrypted := decrypt(l_encrypted, l_key);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_decrypted);

end;
```